# Password automatically changed on DB while update personal details usin cake PHP

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

if i update any of this personal details filed then i click on save it. its save the new data and change my login password also to random value

```
public function update_personal_details() {
     $this->layout = null ;
     $this->autoRender = false;

     $response = array('success' => true);
     if ($this->request->isPost()) {
        if($this->User->exists($this->Auth->user('id'))) {
          try {          
            $this->User->read(null, $this->Auth->user('id'));
            $this->User->set('first_name',$this->request->data["first_name"]);
            $this->User->set('last_name',$this->request->data["last_name"]);
            $this->User->set('mobile',$this->request->data["mobile"]);
            $this->User->set('city',$this->request->data["city"]);
            $this->User->save();
          } catch (exception $ex) {
             $response['success'] = false;
          }
        }
     }  

     return json_encode($response);
  }
```

Comment: See [working-with-passwords-in-cakephp](http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/08/25/working-with-passwords-in-cakephp/) and how to use alias fields to not mess up the save when no password is actually submitted.

Answer (score 1):

To make sure that cakePHP only updates the wanted cols you can pass the data and a field list on the `save` command:

```
Model::save(array $data = null, boolean $validate = true, array $fieldList = array())
```

Just have a look at [Cookbook Save your Data](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html)

For you this should work:

```
$data = array();
$data['first_name'] = $this->request->data["first_name"]);
$data['last_name'] = $this->request->data["last_name"]);
$data['mobile'] = $this->request->data["mobile"]);
$data['city'] = $this->request->data["city"]);

$this->User->save(array('User' => $data), true, array('first_name', 'last_name', 'mobile', 'city'));
```

Hope that helps

Comment: That would effectively render the password input useless in the form, though. It is better to use aliases, see my comment above.

Comment: this approach is more secure, if you forget the csrf protection. Use it, and you will sure that only these fields will be updated